# jQuery: change icon to greyscale

Tags: jquery, colors, icons

I made a button widget in jQuery which displays an icon.

Now when I set the button do disabled, I'd like to have it greyed-out.

Is there a jQuery function to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't want to create another version of the image then you can try using CSS to reduce the opacity of the button so it appears faded, or overlay a semi-transparent grey DIV to give a greyed-out effect.

Comment: as it's icons in my case i prefer this quick solution :)

Answer (score 2):

http://www.alistapart.com/articles/sprites2/

Sprites are your answer.